# Multiple selection by clicking and dragging

Tags: javascript, html, css

[I want to create the option to select a few days by dragging and clicking together.
I did try by dragging, but it doesn't suit me, I want them to also click the mouse
What is the way to set a click and drag action together, I made an attempt to set a click and drag event like this:

```
// $ ("body"). on ('click mouseover', ". button", (event) => {
```

But in actuality it refers to the event when either pressing or dragging, I don't want to be able to drag alone without clicking

Thank you

[Link to code in codepen](https://codepen.io/ataraya/pen/WNbdJRz)

I want to create the option to select a few days by dragging and clicking together.
I did try by dragging, but it doesn't suit me, I want them to also click the mouse
What is the way to set a click and drag action together, I made an attempt to set a click and drag event like this:

```
$ ("body"). on ('click mouseover', ". button", (event) => {});
```

But in actuality it refers to the event when either pressing or dragging, I don't want to be able to drag alone without clicking

Thank you

```js
 "use strict"; 

 $(document).ready( () => {
    
    // 
    $("body").on('click',".all_buttons" , (event) => { 
      
      if( $( ".all_buttons" ).hasClass( "point" )){
         $( ".button" ).each(function( index ) {
              $(this).prev('input').prop( "checked", false );
          });
          $( ".all_buttons" ).removeClass('point');
       } else {
           $( ".button" ).each(function( index ) {
                $(this).prev('input').prop( "checked", true );
            });
          $( ".all_buttons" ).addClass('point');
       }
    
    });
// 
  // $("body").on('click mouseover',".button" , (event) => { 
    $("body").on('click mousedown',".button" , (event) => { 
      
     $(event.currentTarget).prev('input').prop("checked", !$(event.currentTarget).prev('input').prop("checked") );

   });  
  
 });
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center
}
$selected-color: orange;

.button-group input{
  display: none;
}

.button-group input:checked + label,
.button-group input:checked + label:active {
  background-color: $selected-color;
}

.checked {
  background-color: $selected-color;
}

form{ 
  direction: rtl;
}
label{
  margin:1px !important;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <form>   
    <h3>Checkbox Button Group with Foundation 6 for sites</h3>
    <p>You can select multiple items at once</p>
    <div class="button-group">
      <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
      <label class="button all_buttons" for="checkbox1">all</label>
      
      <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">  
      <label class="button" for="checkbox2">Sunday</label>
      
      <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
      <label class="button" for="checkbox3">Monday</label>
      
      <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
      <label class="button" for="checkbox4">Tuesday</label>
      
      <input id="checkbox5" type="checkbox">
      <label class="button" for="checkbox5">Wednesday</label>
      
      <input id="checkbox6" type="checkbox">
      <label class="button" for="checkbox6">Thursday</label>
      
      <input id="checkbox7" type="checkbox">
      <label class="button" for="checkbox7">Friday</label>     
  
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: To recap your confusing question... You want to: mouse-down on i.e: button 2; keep the mouse button pressed; Move the mouse to i.e:  button 4; And actually make buttons 2, 3 and 4 "selected" and trigger an action on all of the selected ones on mouse-up? (PS: From a UX/UI standpoint, it's not something anyone is going to do...)

Comment: Radiobuttons by definition can only be one thing, you want checkboxes.

Comment: Also, what if one starts the "multiple-selection" and ends up highlighting also the "All" button?